# Unable to stop server after closing Spring Source Tool Suite

Tags: java, spring, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I closed STS while vmware vfabric tc server developer edition was still running and now I am unable to stop the server from STS. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete and add the server again, it might help.

Answer (score 0):

Just go to server installation directory and stop the server (probably it should be shutdown.sh).. then try to restart from sts tool it should work fine..

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me:

```
sudo lsof -i tcp:8080
kill -15 PID
```

where pid is the pid of the process you've got with the first command.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/49542432/3793165