# 8080 port already taken issue when trying to redeploy project from Spring Tool Suite IDE

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, spring-boot

I have strange thing when I try to modify Spring project inside my Spring Tool Suite. On the first load (deploy) everything is fine, application compiles and runs on localhost:8080

When I change something inside code and try to redeploy it (Run it again - Run As Spring Boot App) I get error message

> *************************** APPLICATION FAILED TO START
>
> ---
>
> Description:
>
> The Tomcat connector configured to listen on port 8080 failed to
>   start. The port may already be in use or the connector may be
>   misconfigured.
>
> Action:
>
> Verify the connector's configuration, identify and stop any process
>   that's listening on port 8080, or configure this application to listen
>   on another port.
>
> 2016-10-19 00:01:22.615  INFO 10988 --- [           main]
>   ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Closing
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@3023df74:
>   startup date [Wed Oct 19 00:01:19 CEST 2016]; root of context
>   hierarchy 2016-10-19 00:01:22.616  INFO 10988 --- [           main]
>   o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed
>   beans on shutdown

If I shutdown process on that port manually everything works fine again, but this can't be right way of redeploying Spring app. Am I doing something wrong here?

I'm using **:: Spring Boot :: (v1.4.1.RELEASE)**

P.S. I'm aware that I can setup some kind of hot-swap mechanism to have automatic reload of page after I change code, but for now I would like to resolve this issue first.

Thanks for any kind of help or info.

Comment: Yes. You need to shutdown the services safely if re-deploying. Then you won't have the service running in the background and creating a port conflict.

Comment: Eclipse (STS) does not support "single instance" Run "configurations" like IntelliJ does. You need to "Terminate" the running one.

Comment: Use this to change port `--server.port=8181`

Comment: check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45531510/1498586

Comment: In my case, I had apache tomcat installed and running previously. Stopping the tomcat service removed this error

Answer (score 114):

It sometimes happen even when we stop running processes in IDE with help of *Red button* , we continue to get same error.

It was resolved with following steps,

1. Check what processes are running at available ports

`netstat -ao |find /i "listening"`

We get following

`TCP    0.0.0.0:7981           machinename:0        LISTENING       2428 TCP    0.0.0.0:7982           machinename:0        LISTENING       2428 TCP    0.0.0.0:8080           machinename:0        LISTENING       12704 TCP    0.0.0.0:8500           machinename:0        LISTENING       2428`

i.e. Port Numbers and what *Process Id*  they are listening to

2. Stop process running at your port number(In this case it is 8080 & Process Id is 12704)

`Taskkill /F /IM 12704` (Note: Mention correct Process Id)

For more information follow these links [Link1](https://thatpieceofcode.blogspot.com/2020/01/spring-boot-application-failed-to-start_5.html) and [Link2](https://workingpieceofcode.wordpress.com/2020/04/20/spring-boot-application-failed-to-start-web-server-failed-to-start-port-8080-was-already-in-use/).

Comment: I found this useful because after closing STS, sometimes the website does not close its local tc server. No amount of clicking red squares helped; additionally, launching from STS and stopping again still did not kill the server sometimes.

Comment: `lsof -nP +c 15 | grep LISTEN` for macOS

Answer (score 73):

For Mac users(`OS X El Capitan`):

You need to kill the port that `localhost:8080` is running on.
To do this, you need to do two commands in the terminal :N

```
sudo lsof -i tcp:8080

kill -15 PID
```

NB! `PID` IS A NUMBER PROVIDED BY THE FIRST COMMAND.

The first command gives you the `PID` for the `localhost:8080`.
Replace the `PID` in the second command with the `PID` that the first command gives you to kill the process running on `localhost:8080`.

Comment: there is no second command. apparently the answer was edited (partially)
however, i checked using the history and it worked for me., thanks.

Comment: @FayzaNawaz I have changed it back to the original based on your comment. Thank you

Answer (score 29):

You have to stop the current process and run your new one. In Eclipse, you can press this button to ReLaunch your application: [image]

Comment: Some of the eclipse doesn't have this option. If unable to find then just try this Window->Preferences, search for Launching.

Select the "Terminate and Relaunch while launching" option. and apply

Answer (score 27):

The reason is one servlet container is already running on port 8080 and you are trying to run another one on port 8080.

- 1. Check what processes are running at available ports.

     - **For Windows :**
     - `netstat -ao |find /i "listening"`
       [image: Image01]

     OR

     - `netstat -ano | find "8080"` (*Note: 8080 is port fail to start*)
       [image: Image02]
- 2. Now try to reLaunch **or** stop your application.

     - **To relaunch:** you can press this button

  [image: Image03]

  - **To stop in windows:**

  Taskkill /F /IM 6592
  *Note: Mention correct Process Id*

  [image: Image04]

  right click on the console and select **terminate/disconnect all**

  - Go to `Task Manager` and end **Java(tm) platform se binary**

  [image: click here to view image]

  [*What is java(tm) platform se binary(Search in google*](https://www.google.com/search?q=what+is+java(tm)+platform+se+binary&oq=what+is+java(tm)+platform+se+binary&aqs=chrome..69i57.26349j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

*Another option is* :

Go to **`application.properties`** file set **`server.port=0`**. This will cause Spring Boot to use a random free port every time it starts.

Comment: Thanks, I used "server.port=0", because I got the message "Port already in use" for all ports I wrote even if they are not in use.

Answer (score 20):

Create `application.properties` file under `src/main/resources` folder and write content as

> server.port=8084

Its runs fine.
But every time before run need to stop application first by click on red button upper on the IDE
[image]

or try

> RightClick on console>click terminate/Disconnect All

Answer (score 18):

In my case, the error occurred as the application was unable to access the keystore for ssl.

Starting the application as root user fixed the issue.

Comment: yes and it does shows up in the error logs as well!

Comment: Thanks man! I wasted a lot of time because I did not read the whole log! I was going crazy checking if some process was still alive

Comment: @CarlosCavero With spring boot, I have noticed that we really need to go through the whole log to notice what the issue might be. Generally, there are many reasons why the last error message might show up, and searching online only for the last message does not show satisfactory results :)

Comment: Exactly! That's why I upvoted your answer. Looking for other reasons than the typical port busy (even I restarted the pc). Ignore your intuition and do not trust the last message :)

Answer (score 11):

If you got any error on your console by saying, “Embedded servlet container failed to start. Port 8080 was already in use.” Then go to application.properties file and add this property “server.port = 8090”.

Actually the default port for spring boot is 8080, if you have something else on that port, the above error will occur. So we are asking spring boot to run on other port by adding “server.port = 8090” in application.properties file.

Answer (score 9):

This is a typical startup failure due to the **embedded servlet container**’s port being in use.

Your embedded tomcat container failed to start because Port 8080 was already in use.

Just Identify and stop the process that's listening on port 8080 or configure (in you **application.properties** file )this application to listen on another port.

Comment: Your solution works. I just want to add how we set it to listen on another port. Just put server.port=9000 in your application.properties

Answer (score 9):

- **SOLUTION 1**

As a solution ,You can change the default port in application.properties by adding this.

```
   server.port = 8090
```

[image]

- **SOLUTION 2**

If the above solution is not working use this solution.
Here we kill the process which used that port using command prompt.

**In my case,**
Port =8090,
PID =22208

**1).** (This use to find PID)

```
netstat -ano | findstr :8090
```

**2).** (Kill that proccess)

```
 taskkill /PID 22208 /F
```

[image]

**Good Luck !**

Answer (score 8):

There are two ways to resolve this issue.Try option 1 first, if it doesn't work try option 2, and your problem is solved.

1) On the top right corner of your console, there is a red button, to stop the spring boot application which is already running on this port just click on the red button to terminate.

2) If the red button is not activated you need to right click on the console and select terminate/disconnect all. Hope this helps.

Bonus tip:- If you want to run your server on a different port of your choice, create a file named application.properties in resource folder of your maven project and write server.port=3000 to run your application on port 3000

Answer (score 6):

> Am I doing something wrong here?

Yes, you are. One servlet container is already running on port 8080 and you are trying to run another one on port 8080 again.

Either restart the server (If there is button for that in STS) or stop and start it

Comment: true, I actually found Relaunch button inside dashboard. I was expecting Run As to somehow automatically remove previous servlet container from 8080 and run new one, but I guess it doesn't work that way.

In any case, there is button inside STS, and it works now.

Answer (score 4):

On Linux Machine, save the bash script and execute it. If you want to free port 8080, Input 8080 when prompted

```
echo "Enter port number to be closed :: "
read port
sudo kill $(sudo lsof -t -i:$port)
```

Answer (score 3):

Just click red button to stop all services on eclipse than re- run application as Spring Boot Application - This worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

Open "localhost:8080" on your browser and see what is running on this port.
I did it and I just found Oracle 10g XE running on background, so I went to start->Services and stopped all oracle services. Then I redo `mvnw spring-boot:run` on IntelliJ and it runs like magic.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using linux system, use the below command.

`fuser -k some_port_number/tcp`  - that will kill that process.

Sample:-

fuser -k 8080/tcp

Second Option: Configure the tomcat to use a new port

Answer (score 3):

first running from CMD :

```
netstat -aon |find /i "listening" |find   "8080"
```

then get PID number and run following command:
let it 199,

```
taskkill /F /PID 199
```

Answer (score 2):

In Spring Boot Application (Using Spring Starter Project) We Have Update Port in Server.xml using Tomcat server and Add this port in application.property( insrc/main/resources)
the code is 
**server.port=8085**

And update Maven Project then run application

Answer (score 2):

There are some processes left in the background on that port, several reasons can cause this problem, but you can solve easily if you end process which is related to 8080 or Spring.

If you are using Linux there is steps how to end process:

1. Open terminal and type command "htop"
2. press key F3(it will allow you to search)
3. Type "8080" if there was no result on 8080 after that try "spring"
4. Then Press F9(KILL) And press "9"(SIGKILL)

this will kill process which is left on 8080 port and let you run application.

Comment: Some might need run `sudo apt install htop`

Answer (score 2):

Print the list of running processes and try to find the one that says `spring` in it. Once you find the appropriate process ID (`PID`), stop the given process.

```sh
ps aux | grep spring
kill -9 INSERT_PID_HERE
```

After that, try and run the application again. If you killed the correct process your port should be freed up and you can start the server again.

Answer (score 2):

You can use list open file command and then kill the process like below.

```
sudo lsof -t -i tcp:8181 | xargs kill -9
```

or

```
sudo lsof -i tcp:8181

kill -9 PID
```

Answer (score 1):

No Need to  manually start  an application every time at time of development to implements changes use 'spring-boot-devtool' maven dependency.

> Automatic Restart : 
>   To use the module you simply need to add it as a dependency in your Maven POM:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

When you have the spring-boot-devtools module included, any classpath file changes will automatically trigger an application restart. We do some tricks to try and keep restarts fast, so for many microservice style applications this technique might be good enough.

Answer (score 1):

Goto Window->Preferences, search for Launching.

Select the "Terminate and Relaunch while launching" option.

Press Apply.

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution for me that worked was to :
- Restart the IDE, since the stop Button was no longer visible.

Comment: If the red button is not activated you need to right click on the console and select terminate/disconnect all.

Answer (score 0):

One line command for MAC users:

```
kill `lsof -i -n -P | grep TCP | grep 8080 | tr -s " " "\n" | sed -n 2p`
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing problem while redeploying, the easiest way would be to **not leave port occupied**. i.e. close the context of your spring application, so that PORT gets closed alongside.

You can do that in these ways:

```
//open context.
ConfigurableApplicationContext appContext = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
...
//in the end, close it
appContext.close();
```

Another way would be, to: open context in **try()** block

```
try(ConfigurableApplicationContext appContext =
 SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args))
{
// your code here
}
```

**try()** will take care of closing the context, therefore the PORT, even if code breaks somewhere, by
calling **AutoCloseable**.

ref: [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)

Answer (score 0):

If someone accidentally stumble on this post and his problem is that application is starting two times instead of once and it obviosly fails because port is already in use by first instantion of application. Try add these parameters in yml / properties file.

spring.devtools.restart.quiet-period: 2000

spring.devtools.restart.poll-interval: 3000

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/25269

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/12760

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#using.devtools.globalsettings.configuring-file-system-watcher

Answer (score 0):

#### # If you are on windows os (1st way)

- open task bar
- right click on running JDK binary process
- [image]
- after right click then click on end task

#### # If you are on windows os (2nd way)

- pres `win+r` -> press enter (open windows command permot)
- [image]
- `Taskkill /F /IM <PID>`

Answer (score 0):

YOU CAN CHANGE THE PORT NUMBER ALSO, TRYING THAT METHOD WILL CHANGE THE ERROR OF PORT 8080

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For Spring Boot 2 and later version add the property to your application configuration file(application.properties or application.yaml):

```
spring.main.web-application-type=WebApplicationType
```

The WebApplicationType can be one of:

- NONE - The application should not run as a web application and should
  not start an embedded web server.
- REACTIVE - The application should run as a reactive web application and should start an embedded reactive web server.
- SERVLET - The application should run as a servlet-based web application and should start an embedded servlet web server.

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck with the similar issue and followed the below steps which resolved my issue.

Please type the following commands in Windows PowerShell. It needs Administrative privileges.

> > netstat -ano | findstr :8080

TCP    0.0.0.0:8080           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       5868

TCP    [::]:8080              [::]:0                 LISTENING       5868

> > taskkill /PID 5868 /F

SUCCESS: The process with PID 5868 has been terminated.

Answer (score 0):

### For MacOS

After changing the port number run this command in terminal

```
lsof -t -i:<PORT_NUMBER> | xargs kill -9
```