# Understanding the netstat output

Tags: linux, networking

```
tcp        0      0  :::111                      :::*                        LISTEN
```

Above is the output of `netstat -nl | grep 111`What is the meaning of :::111 segment?

Comment: possible duplicate http://superuser.com/questions/661188/what-is-in-the-local-address-of-netstat-output

Comment: mention in answer section . I will accept

Comment: `::` is localhost, the next `:` separates the IP address from the port number, and `111` is the port number.

Comment: answers in these would also help https://superuser.com/questions/515379/what-is-the-difference-between-and-0-0-0-0-from-the-netstat-an-output/1239967#1239967

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**technet.microsoft.com** says that:

> Displays active TCP connections, ports on which the computer is
>   listening, Ethernet statistics, the IP routing table, IPv4 statistics
>   (for the IP, ICMP, TCP, and UDP protocols), and IPv6 statistics (for
>   the IPv6, ICMPv6, TCP over IPv6, and UDP over IPv6 protocols). Used
>   without parameters, netstat displays active TCP connections.

So you can find which addresses and ports are used and listening. for example you want to run a **Tomcat** server on port **8080**. but it used. so you can run:

```
netstat -ano | find "8080"
```

output will be something like:

```
 TCP    0.0.0.0:8080           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       1185
 TCP    [::]:8080              [::]:0                 LISTENING       1185
```

It says that process number **1185** is using this port. If it is necessary to use this port you can shutdown the app that use this port and run your server on it by this command:

```
taskkill /F /PID 1185
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
:myline
netstat -nob
echo.
echo.
ping 127.0.0.1 > %temp%\pingio.txt
goto myline
```

Put this in a batch file and run it as Administrator to monitor network processes.