# Spring Boot application in eclipse, the Tomcat connector configured to listen on port XXXX failed to start

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, tomcat, spring-boot

I'm developing a REST API using Spring Framework.

First I wasn't able to run my application because of the same problem. The port 8080 on my computer is busy. 
Then I found out that one alternative to solve this problem is creating an `application.properties` file under `src/main/resources` folder. 
That's what I made, and set up the server to listen on port 8090. This worked but only for the first time, now I'm getting the same exception whenever I try to run the application for the second time.

```
Description:

The Tomcat connector configured to listen on port 8090 failed to start. The port may already be in use or the connector may be misconfigured.

Action:

Verify the connector's configuration, identify and stop any process that's listening on port 8090, or configure this application to listen on another port.
```

As far as I know, this framework makes use of an embedded instance of apache tomcat to deploy every application.

My guess is, the server is not getting restarted the second time I try to run the app, that's why the output says " The port may already be in use or the connector may be misconfigured"

So, a more specific question would be, how can I manage the embedded instance of apache tomcat either manually or programmatically?

I've also modified the port in the `application.properties` file twice. It works fine, but again, only for the first time. As you can imagine I cannot do the same each time the app is going to be executed.

Comment: Are you stopping the application before you try to start it the second time? If so, how are you doing that? It sounds like the first instance of the application is still running.

Comment: No, I'm not. I actually thought the framework would perform this operations behind the scenes.

Comment: For a temporary workaround, you can set the port to `server.port=0` which will find a random open port to use. Although I suggest you find out a way to stop your application properly.

Comment: It's working fine applying the solution you gave me. Thank you for finding the time to ask this question.

Comment: Hi @codingbash, Lyk yu mentioned, i made my port number as 0 in the properties file. Still, I'm getting the same error.


"The Tomcat connector configured to listen on port 0 failed to start. The port may already be in use or the connector may be misconfigured.
"

any guess on my issue??

Answer (score 42, accepted):

On the console, looking at the topmost right side of the dialog you should see a red button kinda like a buzzer. To stop the spring boot application properly you just ran, go ahead and hit this button and your problem is solved. Hope this helps!

Comment: If eclipse isn't the one using the port find which one is and kill it. stackoverflow.com/a/47235112/1308453

Comment: This issue arises because of other service or tomcat using the port already running. NOTE: STS runs tomcat from its own end and if tomcat is pre running then you need to stop the service. As mentioned in other posts you need to stop the service. The solution mentioned above talks about stopping the server if it has pre-run using STS only.

Comment: Just try to close your IDE and run your application again.

Comment: Or just click blue icon in left side of screen and solve the problem withouth stopping the application. Its easy

Answer (score 106):

1. Find the process ID (PID) for the port (e.g.: **8080**)

   On Windows:

   ```
   netstat -ao | find "8080"
   ```

   Other Platforms other than windows :

   ```
   lsof -i:8080
   ```
2. Kill the process ID you found (e.g.: 20712)

   On Windows:

   ```
   Taskkill /PID  20712 /F
   ```

   Other Platforms other than windows :

   ```
   kill -9 20712   or kill 20712
   ```

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks a lot. But not sure why even after killing the server from IntelliJ, it is not killing the process. This is happening always for me

Comment: This worked for me as well. However, it must be said that even after restarting the server once I completed this task I still got the same error but my application ran.

Comment: for windows try `netstat -ano -p tcp |find "9443"`

Answer (score 25):

Another easy way of solving this error is right clicking in the console and click on Terminate/Disconnect All. Afterwards run the application it should work fine.

Answer (score 15):

**Issue**: It's because either you are not stopping your application or the application is already somehow running on the same port somehow.

**Solution**, Before starting it another time, the earlier application needs to be killed and the port needs to be freed up.

Depending on your platform you can run the below commands to stop the application,

**on windows**

> netstat -anp | find "your application port number"` --> find PID
>
> taskkill /F /PID

**on Linux,**

> netstat -ntpl | grep "your application port number"
>
> kill pid // pid you will get from previous command

**on Mac OS**

> lsof -n -iTCP:"port number"
>
> kill pid //pid you will get from previous command

Comment: I've tried those commands before however, the real problem is that the application doesn't run in the same port twice.

Comment: @Sandoval0992 As i said, its because before restarting, you are not stopping the application.

Comment: @100Pixels I am having same trouble now. How did you fix this problem ?

Comment: @want2learn I've just marked the accepted answer, this is what I did. Just stop your boot application before trying to run it again. Click the "stop" button from the "servers" perspective. It's on the top right corner of this window.

Comment: In Cygwin
$ netstat -anp | find "8080"
find: ‘8080’: No such file or directory

 
$ netstat -ntpl | grep "8080"
Displays protocol statistics... (showing help).

In CMD:
netstat -anp
returns empty

Comment: This answer has the correct commands. https://stackoverflow.com/a/47235112/1308453

Answer (score 14):

Find the process and terminate it. 
On Windows do a Control+Alt+Delete and then find the "Java(TM) Platform SE Binary" process under the Processes Tab. For example: 
[image]

On Ubuntu, you can use "ps aux | grep java" to find the process and "kill -9 PID_NUMBER" to kill the process.

OR

If you're using a Spring boot application, go to application.properties and add this:

```
server.port = 8081
```

Comment: Still it is not working for any other ports as well.. Please help.

Comment: Sorry, you're question is too ambiguous. Maybe post it as a new question and include your more background situational information. Like your OS, Error messages, etc.

Comment: Works for me on Windows, but need to know which process to kill if you're running multiple services.

Comment: Knowing how to change the port is what I really need, as another app already runs on port 8080, and I cannot simply kill it.

Answer (score 7):

In case your app is run on httpS, make sure you put right values under the following properties:

```
server.ssl.key-store-password=
server.ssl.key-alias=
```

I got the same error when I put the wrong values here

Comment: Thank you. I had wrong values here. :( Correcting it worked :)

Comment: Same here. I left the alias-password empty

Answer (score 4):

**On Windows:**

To get started, open the command prompt by clicking on Start and then typing cmd. In the command window, go ahead and type in the following command:

> netstat -a -n -o

In the command above, the -o parameter is what will add the PID to the end of the table. Press enter and you should see something like this:

[image]

Now to see the name of the process that is using that port, go to Task Manager by pressing CTRL + SHIFT + ESC and then click on the Process tab. In Windows 10, you should click on the Details tab.

By default, the task manager does not display the process ID, so you have to click on View and then Select Columns.

You might also need to look into services running in background. To do that right-click and select open services as shown below:

[image]

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 4):

this issue can be resolved using 2 ways:

1. Kill application running on 8080

> ```
> netstat -ao | find "8080"
>
> Taskkill /PID 1342 /F
> ```

2. change spring server port in **application.properties** file

> server.port=8081

Answer (score 2):

1. check the port which is busy: netstat -ntlp
2. kill that port : kill -9 xxxx

Answer (score 2):

The easier way to solve this is changing the port on the ***application.properties*** file;

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7sNO2.png)

server.port=8081

Answer (score 1):

**There are two options to handle/avoid this situation.**

1. Before re-running the application just terminate the previous connection.

- `Open the console --> right click --> terminate all.`

2. If you forgot to perform action mention on step 1 then

- Figure out the port used by your application, you could see it the stack trace
  in the console window
- Figure out the process id associated to port by executing **netstat -aon** command in cmd
- Kill that process and re-run the application.

Answer (score 0):

if it's convenient for you, and you don't want to use the command line, you can **reboot** your computer, it helps!

Answer (score 0):

For those who are experiencing same problem after controlling there is no suspicious java process which allocate the port, there is no red square on eclipse to terminate any process and also there is no change even you try different port for your spring boot application.

might sound stupid but; restarting eclipse works. :)

Answer (score 0):

In your windows os follow the following steps:

---

### 1)search services
2)Find Apache tomcat
3)Right-click on it and select end
4)Run your spring boot application again it will work

Answer (score 0):

We have had the same issue in eclipse or intellij. After trying many alternative solutions, I found simple solution - add this config to your application.properties:
`spring.main.web-application-type=none`

Answer (score 0):

If you have devtools like auto build dependency remove it. It is automatically build your project and run it. When you build manually it show port in use.

Answer (score 0):

If none of the solutions above worked and you are using IntelliJ Idea (I'm using version 2020.3) you can go on your services tab and try to right click on your running configuration then click on clear content.

[image: running server]

Answer (score 0):

OS assigns a special number known as Process Identifier (PID) which is unique for every process and running port. And killing the process which running on your preferred port will clear the blockage to deploy your application on that port.

- **Step 1:**
  Find the process ID (PID) for the port (e.g.: 8080)

On Windows:

```
netstat -ao | find "8080"
```

- **Step 2:**
  Kill the process ID you found (e.g.: 20712)

On Windows in cmd right click and open  run as administrator:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNwLZ.png)

```
Taskkill /PID  20712 /F
```

Answer (score 0):

For Spring Boot 2 and later version add the property to your application configuration file(application.properties or application.yaml):

```
spring.main.web-application-type=SERVLET
```

The WebApplicationType can be one of:

- NONE - The application should not run as a web application and should
  not start an embedded web server.
- REACTIVE - The application should run as a reactive web application and should start an embedded reactive web server.
- SERVLET - The application should run as a servlet-based web application and should start an embedded servlet web server.

Answer (score -1):

[image: right click on console and stop]

right click on your console and terminate. or click on stop

[image]