# org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.ConnectorStartFailedException on IDEA Ultimate 2019.3

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a project in which I'm working that it is made, among everything, with Java 11+Spring Boot+Gradle.
All of a sudden, when I press play on IntelliJ Idea Ultimate 2019.3 I'm getting the following error.

```
<String that tells the given command for launching the app>
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.4.RELEASE)

org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.ConnectorStartFailedException: Connector configured to listen on port 8080 failed to start
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.checkConnectorHasStarted(TomcatWebServer.java:232)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.checkThatConnectorsHaveStarted(TomcatWebServer.java:224)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.start(TomcatWebServer.java:202)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.startWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:311)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.finishRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:164)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:552)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248)
    at it.niuma.epp.EPPApplication.main(EPPApplication.java:79)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

And that's just it. The code of the Main class is made just by these lines

```
@EnableScheduling
@EnableAsync
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {list of packages})
public class EPPApplication implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /* Allows slash url encoding */
        // System.setProperty("org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.UDecoder.ALLOW_ENCODED_SLASH",
        // "true");
            SpringApplication.run(EPPApplication.class, args);

    }
```

And if I don't surround the SpringApplication.run in a try-catch scope, I wouldn't even get the error. 
The project tries to boot on port 8080, which is not occupied by anything. In fact, by typing

```
netstat -ano|findstr "PID :8080"
```

on my Windows machine, this is the result shown

```
C:\Users\Gianmarco>netstat -ano|findstr "PID :8080"
  Proto  Indirizzo locale          Indirizzo esterno        Stato           PID
  TCP    0.0.0.0:8080           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       18152
  TCP    [::]:8080              [::]:0                 LISTENING       18152
```

When if I try to change to any other port possible, I always get the same error.

What am I missing? I've tried to see other similar questions on SO but nobody had my same issue

EDIT: The same happens on Eclipse as well

EDIT2: By following the debbuger starting from `org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal()`  I see that it even reaches the logger part in which it states that has started tomcat on port 8080 but this isn't logged on the console. Shortly after, I reach SpringApplication.java on line 400 which calls line 327 in which I see that a variable colled exceptionReporters (a collection) holds an expection. The following screenshot represent what this collection holds. After this point, though, it looks like I can't debug anymore but the application remains stuck

[image]

application.properties

EDIT3: As requested, here's my application.properties, my build.gradle

```
server.port=8080
application.base.path=/opt/epp
spring.datasource.tomcat.minSize=35
spring.datasource.tomcat.initialSize=35
spring.datasource.tomcat.maxActive=250

logging.config=file:config/logback.xml

datasource.type = oracle

# spring.mvc.throw-exception-if-no-handler-found=true
# spring.resources.add-mappings=false
# spring.mvc.static-path-pattern=/**
# spring.resources.static-locations=classpath:/static/

#MAIL CONFIG
spring.mail.default-encoding=UTF-8
[...]


# FROM OLD INTERNAL APPLICATION.PROPERTIES
server.servlet.context-path=/epp
spring.session.store-type=none
#logging.level.org.springframework.web=INFO
#logging.file=log/asta.log
#logging.pattern.file=="%d{dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c:%L]-> %m%n
spring.mustache.expose-session-attributes=true
spring.mustache.allow-request-override=true
#spring.mustache.allow-session-override=true
#server.session.cookie.max-age=60
#server.session.timeout=60
# Charset of HTTP requests and responses. Added to the "Content-Type" header if not set explicitly.
spring.http.encoding.charset=UTF-8
# Enable http encoding support.
spring.http.encoding.enabled=true
# Force the encoding to the configured charset on HTTP requests and responses.
spring.http.encoding.force=true
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=150MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=150MB
spring.mustache.suffix=.html

####### DEV ONLY, TO CHANGE IN PRODUCTION ##########
#logging.level.org.springframework.security=DEBUG
# see ldap.enabled
ldap.mock_email = false
debug.clientTrace = false
remember_me.cookie_only = true
remember_me.enabled_by_default = false
spring.mustache.cache = true
spring.cache.type = simple

#GESTIONE APERTURA VALUTAZIONE DA PARTE DEL BUYER
flg.can.buyer.evaluate=true
flg.gestione.prequalifica=false

#soglia di sbarramento in percentuale
soglia.sbarramento = 40

# in ambiente integrato va decommentato
# server.servlet.session.cookie.name = MYSESSIONID


zip.buffer.size = 8192
```

build.gradle

```
buildscript {
  dependencies {
    classpath ("org.hidetake:gradle-ssh-plugin:2.8.0")
  }
}

plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.4.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    id 'eclipse-wtp'
    id "org.zeroturnaround.gradle.jrebel" version "1.1.8"
}

apply plugin: 'org.hidetake.ssh'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

jar.dependsOn(generateRebel)

compileJava {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8' 
}

bootJar {
    launchScript()
}

springBoot {
    buildInfo {
        properties {
            artifact = 'EPP-ORDER NTT'
            version = project.hasProperty('buildversion') ? buildversion: ''
            group = 'it.niuma.epp'
            name = 'test+order'
            additionalProperties = [
                operatingSystem: "${System.properties['os.name']} (${System.properties['os.version']})",
                //machine: InetAddress.localHost.hostName,
            ]
        }       
    }
}

archivesBaseName = project.hasProperty('archives_base_name') ? archives_base_name : 'epp'
ext.jarPath = project.hasProperty('jarPath') ? "${projectDir}/${jarPath}" : "${buildDir}/libs/epp.jar"

//archivesBaseName = project.hasProperty('archives_base_name') ? archives_base_name : 'supplier_portal'
//ext.jarPath = project.hasProperty('jarPath') ? "${projectDir}/${jarPath}" : "${buildDir}/libs/supplier_portal.jar"

ext.deployPath = project.hasProperty('deployPath') ? deployPath : '/opt/epp'

sourceCompatibility = 11
targetCompatibility = 11

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
      url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
    }
}

dependencies {
    // Framework - START
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest')
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc')
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-websocket')
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mustache')
    implementation('com.github.sps.mustache:mustache-spring-view:1.4')
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail')
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web-services')
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security')
    implementation('org.springframework.security:spring-security-ldap')

    // required by LDAP (spring-ldap bug?)
    implementation group: 'commons-pool', name: 'commons-pool', version: '1.6'

    // required by Logback for conditional processing
    implementation group: 'org.codehaus.janino', name: 'janino', version: '3.0.12'

    // Framework - END

    // DB - START
    implementation('org.sql2o:sql2o:1.6.0-RC3')
    implementation group: 'com.microsoft.sqlserver', name: 'mssql-jdbc', version: '7.2.1.jre11'
    // FOR INTEGRATION TEST DB
    implementation files('libs/ojdbc8.jar')
    implementation('org.sql2o.extensions:sql2o-oracle:1.6.0-RC3') {
        exclude group:'com.oracle'
    }
    // DB - END

    // Excel support - START
    implementation('org.apache.poi:poi:3.16')
    implementation('org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:3.16') {
        exclude group:'stax', module: 'stax-api'
    }
    // Excel support - END

    // Cerved - START
    implementation files('libs/CervedObject.jar')
    implementation files('libs/CervedWebServices.jar')
    implementation group: 'com.sun.xml.bind', name: 'jaxb-impl', version: '2.3.2'
    implementation group: 'com.sun.istack', name: 'istack-commons-runtime', version: '3.0.8'
    // Cerved - END

    // START FLYING SAUCER
    implementation group: 'org.xhtmlrenderer', name: 'flying-saucer-pdf-openpdf', version: '9.1.18'
    implementation group: 'org.jsoup', name: 'jsoup', version: '1.11.3'
    // END FLYING SAUCER

    // START DSS
    implementation('org.digidoc4j.dss:dss-pades:5.2.d4j.3')
    implementation group: 'org.digidoc4j.dss', name: 'dss-service', version: '5.2.d4j.3'
    implementation group: 'org.digidoc4j.dss', name: 'dss-token', version: '5.2.d4j.3'
    implementation group: 'org.digidoc4j.dss', name: 'dss-utils-apache-commons', version: '5.2.d4j.3'
    // END DSS

    // START UNIT TEST 1
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test") {
        exclude group: 'junit', module: 'junit'
    }
    testImplementation group: 'org.junit.jupiter', name: 'junit-jupiter-api', version: '5.4.2'
    testImplementation group: 'org.junit.jupiter', name: 'junit-jupiter-params', version: '5.4.2'
    testImplementation group: 'org.junit.jupiter', name: 'junit-jupiter-engine', version: '5.4.2'
    testImplementation group: 'org.junit.platform', name: 'junit-platform-commons', version: '1.4.2'
    testImplementation group: 'org.junit.platform', name: 'junit-platform-launcher', version: '1.4.2'
    // END UNIT TEST 1

    // MISCELLANEOUS - START

    implementation group: 'org.iban4j', name: 'iban4j', version: '3.2.1'
    implementation group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-validator', version: '6.0.8.Final'
    implementation 'com.opencsv:opencsv:4.0'
    implementation group: 'org.unbescape', name: 'unbescape', version: '1.1.6.RELEASE'

    // MISCELLANEOUS - END


    /***** TOREMOVE - START *****/

    // iText 5 - START
    implementation('com.itextpdf:itextpdf:5.5.11')
    implementation('com.itextpdf.tool:xmlworker:5.5.11')
    // iText 5 - END

    /***** TOREMOVE - END *****/



    /* ORDER Dependecies */
    compile group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.7'
    compile group: 'org.digidoc4j.dss', name: 'dss-utils-google-guava', version: '5.2.d4j.3'
    compile group: 'org.xhtmlrenderer', name: 'flying-saucer-pdf-openpdf', version: '9.1.12'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.xml.ws/jaxws-rt
    compile group: 'com.sun.xml.ws', name: 'jaxws-rt', version: '2.3.2'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.passay/passay
    compile group: 'org.passay', name: 'passay', version: '1.4.0'

    // SWAGGER
    /*****compile group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-swagger-ui', version: '2.9.2'
    compile group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-swagger2', version: '2.9.2'

   // LOMBOK
    compile group: 'org.projectlombok', name: 'lombok', version: '1.18.10' *****/

   // MODEL MAPPER
    compile group: 'org.modelmapper.extensions', name: 'modelmapper-spring', version: '2.3.2'






}


// START UNIT TEST 2
test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
test.enabled = gradle.startParameter.taskNames.contains('test') || gradle.startParameter.taskNames.contains('check')
// END UNIT TEST 2

// Remote administration - START

remotes {
  server {
    deleted sensible data
  }
}

ssh.settings {
  logging = 'stdout'
    knownHosts = allowAnyHosts
}

task copyjar {
  doLast {
    if (!project.hasProperty('ip')){
      logger.lifecycle("No IP - Launch with -Pip=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx");
      throw new StopExecutionException()
    }

    logger.lifecycle("Copying... <$jarPath to $deployPath>") 

    ssh.run{
      session(remotes.server) {
        put from: jarPath, into: deployPath
      }
    }
  }
}

task stopServer {
  doLast {
    if (!project.hasProperty('ip')){
      logger.lifecycle("No IP - Launch with -Pip=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx");
      throw new StopExecutionException()
    }
    logger.lifecycle("Execute stopServer on $remotes.server.host");

    if (project.hasProperty('cmd')){
        cmd = project.hasProperty('cmd') ? cmd : ''
        ssh.run {
        session(remotes.server) {
           execute cmd
        }
      }
    } else {
    ssh.run {
      session(remotes.server) {
        execute 'sudo systemctl stop epp.service'
      }
    }
  }
}
}

task startServer{
  doLast {
    if (!project.hasProperty('ip')){
      logger.lifecycle("No IP - Launch with -Pip=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx");
      throw new StopExecutionException()
    }
    logger.lifecycle("Execute stopServer on $remotes.server.host");

    if (project.hasProperty('cmd')){
        cmd = project.hasProperty('cmd') ? cmd : ''
        ssh.run {
           session(remotes.server) {
              execute cmd
           }
        }
    } else {
      ssh.run {
        session(remotes.server) {
        execute 'sudo systemctl start epp.service'
         }
      }
    }
  }
}

// Remote administration - STOP

task copyBuildFiles(type: Copy) {
    from file("application.properties")
    into ("$buildDir/libs/")
}

build.dependsOn(copyBuildFiles)
```

Comment: Is there any earlier log output? Tomcat should log something when it fails to start the connector. Failing that, you could debug the application with a breakpoint on `org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal()` and step through the code to see what the failure actually is.

Comment: Have you tried with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43026358/spring-boot-application-in-eclipse-the-tomcat-connector-configured-to-listen-on

Comment: Somewhat related, if that's all the output that's being produced, you may have a problem with some logging related dependencies. For example, a dependency on `commons-logging:commons-logging` can caused problems and should be excluded in favour of `spring-jcl`.

Comment: @PatelRomil yes, no luck at all

Comment: @AndyWilkinson I don't have a dependency like commons-logging, so I wouldn't really now even where to start to eliminate dependecies... As for the debugger, I've followed all the process and it doesn't bring to a crash point. It even reaches the logger part in which it states that has started tomcat on port 8080 but this isn't logged on the console. Shortly after, I reach SpringApplication.java on line 400 which calls line 327 in which I see that a variable colled exceptionReporters (a collection) holds an expection. Screen in the post

Comment: But from your net stat output is shows that something is listening on port 8080... Hence tomcat cannot connect. If there was nothing on the port nothing would be in the output? (Unless net stat on windows works differently :) ). Can you add your `application.properties` and `pom.xml` or output of `mvn dependency:tree` to your post.

Comment: @M.Deinum Whatever port I specify it won't boot, no matter what. Even if I try to kill the process on port, for example, 8080. I've added my application.properties and build.gradle as requested (we are using Gradle, not Maven)

Comment: You don't have a direct dependency on `commons-logging:commons-logging`, but it is being pulled in transitively. You can learn where it's coming from by running `gradle dependencyInsight --dependency commons-logging:commons-logging`. You also have a transitive dependency on `org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j` which you should exclude as well.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson yes, excluding commons-logging definetely worked! If you make that as an answer, I'll accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the lack of logging output, you may have a problem with some logging related dependencies. For example, a dependency on `commons-logging:commons-logging` can cause problems and should be excluded in favour of `org.springframework:spring-jcl`. `org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j` should be treated similarly.

You can learn if you have either of these dependencies on the classpath using Gradle's `dependencyInsight` task:

```
gradle dependencyInsight --dependency commons-logging:commons-logging
gradle dependencyInsight --dependency org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j
```

Comment: By excluding globally the suggested modules, I was able to have the application start once again. Thank you!