# How to solve error: The port may already be in use or the connector may be misconfigured

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat

My application is giving error while startup.

> The Tomcat connector configured to listen on port 51000 failed to
> start. The port may already be in use or the connector may be
> misconfigured.

When I check the port, it seems it is available.

```
netstat -aon | findstr 0.0:51000
-aon |find /i "listening" |find "51000"
```

How can I fix this issue without changing the port?

Comment: Did you also try using `netstat -aon | findstr "51000"`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Boot application in eclipse, the Tomcat connector configured to listen on port XXXX failed to start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43026358/spring-boot-application-in-eclipse-the-tomcat-connector-configured-to-listen-on)