# Stopping specific Spring Boot applications among many

Tags: spring-boot, process, pid

I have a few Spring Boot Application jars which have been started up by running:

```
java -jar Application1.jar
java -jar Application2.jar
java -jar Application3.jar
```

I want to stop a specific Spring Boot app (for example `Application1`) but when I list all running processes, I will have a list like:

```
Image Name                     PID Session Name        Session#    Mem Usage
========================= ======== ================ =========== ============
java.exe                     17932 Console                    1     70,928 K
java.exe                     15666 Console                  ...      .......
```

How do I stop the specific Spring Boot process?

Or is there a way to start up a Spring Boot application and give it a customised process's name so I can stop it in the future?

Comment: did you start these on some specific port ?@hydradon

Comment: @rdj7 yes, I have a port number in a properties file

Comment: If Application1.jar, Application2.jar, Application3.jar contain properties file mentioning what port it is running on then you can follow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40118878/8080-port-already-taken-issue-when-trying-to-redeploy-project-from-spring-tool-s/47235112#47235112

Comment: If you're using Linux, you can deploy Spring Boot app as separate service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You need to check which processes are running on which port, use the following command

   `netstat -ao |find /i "listening"`

[image: You get the following result]

2.As you mentioned you have the port number for the specific application you need to stop. for example, you need to stop application running on port 8080. Notice the process id for that particular port number(last column for port:8080 process id:14024)

3.Stop process running at your port number `Taskkill /F /IM 14024`
you will get the following result.
[image]

Hope this helps!