# Web server failed to start. Port 8080 was already in use while re-debugging spring boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, debugging, gradle, tomcat

I am trying to run my Spring boot application in debug mode {Intellij Idea}.
When I debug the application for the first time, it works. However, on stopping the process and running the application again gives me this error.

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************
Description:
Web server failed to start. Port 8080 was already in use.
Action:
Identify and stop the process that's listening on port 8080 or configure this application to listen on another port.

> Task :bootRun FAILED
Execution failed for task ':bootRun'.
> Process '..\jdk11.0.16_9\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

The problem is that port 8080 doesn't get released when I stop the execution.
If I try to manually kill the process using `taskkill /pid <pid> /f`, then I am able to re-run the application, but I have to repeat manually killing the previous process on port 8080 every time I want to re-run the application. Is there a way to overcome this issue?

TIA!

Comment: I think this thread can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40118878/8080-port-already-taken-issue-when-trying-to-redeploy-project-from-spring-tool-s

Comment: @FabricioEntringerMoreira Most of the answers suggest killing the process that is occupying the port. I am already doing this, but force killing the process manually every time doesn't seem to be solution. Is there anything specific on this thread that I should try?

Answer (score 0):

You can do `netsh winsock reset` and restart the PC.